Combing two subqueries and use either of the value depends on which one is not null



There tables are there VAC_NRD, VAC_DOC, VAC_TRV.
If this query return VAC_ID empty.

SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_NRD WHERE VAC_NRD =?

Will use this query to get VAC_ID
2. (SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_DOC WHERE VAC_DOC =?)

Use the retrieved VAC_ID value here to fetch the final result
SELECT  * FROM VAC_TRV WHERE VAC_ID = ?

Is there any way I can achieve this using one query, by adding subquery or any other way.
SELECT  * FROM VAC_TRV WHERE VAC_ID =(SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_DOC WHERE VAC_DOC =?………)


There tables are there VAC_NRD, VAC_DOC, VAC_NRD. ... you listed VAC_NCR twice, is that a typo?  If there is a third table, please provide the subquery for that one too.

It's a typo. updated now.

Can't you simply write ...WHERE vac_id IN (COALESCE((SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_NRD WHERE VAC_NRD = ?),(SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_DOC WHERE VAC_DOC =?)))?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

You could try doing a full outer join of the two tables, then selecting the VAC_ID from the appropriate table using COALESCE():
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(nrd.VAC_ID, doc.VAC_ID) AS VAC_ID
    FROM VAC_NRD nrd
    FULL OUTER JOIN VAC_DOC doc
        ON doc.VAC_ID = nrd.VAC_ID
    WHERE
        nrd.VAC_NRD = ? OR
        doc.VAC_DOC = ?
)

SELECT *
FROM VAC_TRV
WHERE VAC_ID IN (SELECT VAC_ID FROM cte);

Note that we preferentially select the VAC_ID from the VAC_NRD source table, if it could be found there.  Otherwise, we fall back to taking VAC_ID from the VAC_DOC table.

@MatBailie I think you may have caught something; I changed the WHERE clause to or the conditions together.

...and that should be fine, right, because COALESCE() would ensure that the NRD result gets preferentially chosen (assuming each table have at most one VAC_ID value.

you can use a CASE statement to decide which subquery to execute:
SELECT * FROM VAC_TRV WHERE VAC_ID = (
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VAC_NRD WHERE VAC_NRD = ?) 
    THEN (SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_NRD WHERE VAC_NRD = ?)
    ELSE (SELECT VAC_ID FROM VAC_DOC WHERE VAC_DOC = ?)
END);


This would only work if both of the subqueries always would return just a single record.  Otherwise, it would fail.
